# Python API - pattern for creating optional parenthesis?

Tags: python, function

I am designing the API for a Python library, and have run into a situation where I think my imagination might have overtaken Python's considerable abilities.

(I want to apologize to any Pythonistas who may get offended by the Ruby-ness of my design)

Basically, there is a class with a few methods on it, each of which returns `self`, so that they can be chained together. So:

```
>>> a = MyKlass()
>>> b = a.method_one()
>>> c = b.method_two()
```

would be the same as

```
>>> a = MyKlass()
>>> c = a.method_one().method_two()
```

My question is whether it is possible to make the parenthesis optional.  I have learned a bit about using `__getattr__` and `__call__` to manipulate callable objects, but haven't been able to fully implement this.  Right now, I have the class's `__getattr__` checking for the attribute, and then determining whether the `name` is a method or attribute (or more accurately, whether it is callable or not).

My problem is that if it is a callable, I need `__getattr__` to do something like this:

```
>>> class MyKlass(object):
>>>     def __getattr__(self, name):
>>>         # pseudocode, you get the idea...
>>>         if name is callable:
>>>             def callme(*args, **kwds):
>>>                 # do stuff
>>>             return callme
>>>         else:
>>>             # just return the attribute
```

So it returns a callable object.  This means, though, that I couldn't make the parenthesis optional, since the callable object would be returned, but never called:

```
>>> a = MyKlass()
>>> c = a.method_one.method_two    # AttributeError, since a bound function object does not have attribute "method_two"
```

The only way I thought of to do this would be to be able to "look ahead" in the code and determine whether the `name` is followed by parenthesis or not. Then, if `name` was callable but not called, I could return the results of calling `name` without arguments instead of returning a callable object.

I am thinking that this is probably not doable, but I thought that I would ask the gurus anyway.

Comment: If it's not a property, then it should not be called implicitly. Don't do that, ever. Especially in a library. Python is not Ruby.

Comment: yes... it is not useful and may cause a lot of confusion for those who will use your library

Comment: I hear you all loud and clear. I am marking @FogleBird's answer as the accepted answer, but I appreciate you all setting me on the straight and narrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're nuts for wanting to do this. What reason do you have? What about methods that take arguments? (See example below.)

It seems to work for methods without arguments if you use `__getattribute__` instead of `__getattr__`.

Working example:

```
class Test(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = super(Test, self).__getattribute__(name)
        if callable(attr):
            return attr()
        return attr
    def f(self):
        print 'f'
        return self
    def g(self):
        print 'g'
        return self
    def h(self, x):
        print x
        return self

t = Test()
t.f.g # Works fine
t.f().g # Fails - the parens aren't optional, they must be left off now
t.f.g.h(1) # Fails - unable to provide an argument
```

To get around the argument issue, you *could* inspect the function and only call it if it doesn't take any arguments (other than self). See: http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Do yourself a favor and stop going down this path.

Comment: What I'm going for, is that the parenthesis are optional if you don't need to pass any arguments to it, and required if you do need to pass arguments.  So `a.method_one.method_two` would actually call `a.method_one().method_two()` while `a.method_one(name='blah').method_two` would actually call `a.method_one(name='blah').method_two()`

Answer (score 3):

Without the parentheses, you have a reference to the function, with them you have the result of its invocation. This is a fundamental part of Python's syntax (this consistency is a good thing!).

You can always use Python's `property` function (or the associated decorator) to make a method work under the hood as an alias for a property which will achieve what you want. However, this suggests you are writing very side-effect-heavy code which is a Bad Idea.

Chaining like this is popular in jQuery because jQuery's sole purpose is to cause side effects in the DOM. Typically this isn't a sensible elsewhere because it makes your application very difficult to debug and test.